# Qual o radical da palavra "depilar"?

Tags: etimologia, morfema

Em um jogo, disse que o radical da palavra "depilar" era "pelo", mas um amigo insiste em dizer que pelo seria radical de "depelar", mas não de "depilar".

Procurei por alguma referência absoluta de que o radical de "depilar" seja "pelo", mas não consegui encontrar.

Answer (score 6):

A verbo "depilar" foi emprestado do latim "*dēpilāre*", literalmente *dē-*, de tirar; *pilus*, pelo; e o final de verbos da primeira conjugação *-āre*.

A razão de haver pElo e não *depElar é a seguinte: *pilum* > *pilu* > pelo. De forma simples, o "i" curto do latim virou "e" no português. Se o português houvesse herdado a palavra *dēpilāre* naturalmente do latim, a palavra seria "*depelar", mas tal fato não ocorreu, apenas emprestamos posteriormente do latim, gerando assim "depilar".

Comment: Para complementar, o Houaiss, diz que *depilar* está atestado em 1881 e remete para o latim; *depilatório* em 1870, do francês. Como o francês *dépiler* está atestado já em 1560, *depilar* poderia muito bem vir de lá também.